# Invalid byte 2 of a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence when i execute the Build project

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

Link of project: https://github.com/GunB/eExcelParser
I'm trying to change a XML based in metadata.xml and it's working correctly when i run `Netbeans` for compile it but when i create the Clean and Build version it throws `Invalid byte 2 of a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence` ... i can't understand why

I'm using this code to read the XML file

```
File fXmlFile = new File(strBase);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

The libraries i'm using are [POI](https://poi.apache.org/), [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), XMLBeans included with POI and [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/dom4j-1.6.1/)

Also the project is sending this warning:

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Warning: Setting Codebase manifest attribute to '*' due to current JNLP Codebase. Set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the non-secure value '*'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML file seems to be converted to a wrong single-byte encoding. Check that using `Reader/Writer/String.getBytes/new String` always a charset is specified. Do never use `FileReader/FileWriter`.

Comment: But why netbeans debug reads the XML correctly? (I'm not using your answer yet, I'm on it)

Comment: You might be using maven or ant applying a wrong recoding. Specifiy UTF-8 everywhere: IDE too. Then there is a copy-filtered-resource-file sometimes, that allows expression-language substitutions, that also could mangle an XML file, copied and recoded in the result. Check the XML in the jar.

Comment: But that's the weird part, the XML is out of the jar. It comes like "program.jar" and "metadata.xml" in the same folder.
The file is read correctly but it's parsed wrongly

Comment: And `<?xml...>` encoding is correct. Use a programmers editor like JEdit or NotePad++ that can do encodings. Do a hex dump (of non-7-bit ASCII). If that is okay, somewhere a Reader or Writer is involved. Do not give up.

Comment: Using your answer i get what i want, now i having another problem but well, Step by step :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, and it works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilderFactory Factory;
    Factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser = Factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = parser.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GunB/eExcelParser/develop/metadata.xml");
}
```

may be you did not save file properly;
i also saved `metada.xml` using curl:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GunB/eExcelParser/develop/metadata.xml
```

when i parse the local file, it also works fine

Comment: It continues sending the same error when I use the clean and build version... i think it's something about config when it builds the project or something... idk. I Also tried using the curl downloaded file like you propose here